# Accessing Windows directory from java application running on linux websphere

Tags: java, linux, file

I am working on an application that generates excel reports from a report generated by Mainframe. 
Input report location and ouput location for generated reports are on company common drive that is mapped on my local windows box. 
Things were wokring fine from my eclipse since my account have access to those locations on common drive. I am using JAVA File io to access common drive. 
But when I deployed on webpshere, it wasn't able to access common drive and I think it could be websphere is using different account to access common drive and that account doesn't have permissions. 
My question is how to force Java File io to use particular account.
And also when I deploy application on linux websphere, will this work assuming, common drive will also be mapped on linux boxes.

Answer (score 1):

The proper account must be specified at the time of mounting the network location. (This can be done in both Windows (`net use` command) and Linux (`mount` command).)
Then, access mounted network location from your Java application.

Comment: The proper account here is the account used by websphere. right?

Comment: The question is, when and how does your network location get mounted and what credentials are used? This usually happens at system startup, before some websphere software gets started. Take a look at `/etc/fstab` and `/etc/mtab` files.